# How can I use .env.example constant in HTML view?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

In my .env.example file, I have defined a constant, e.g. BUSINESS_ID=1234

I would like to use this constant in my test.blade.php file like so:

```
<p>{{ env.example(BUSINESS_ID) }}</p>
```

But Laravel doesn't like this formatting - please advise as to how I can call the constant from the .env.example file to appear on the front-end. Thanks.

Comment: FYI: `.env.example` is never loaded. It's, surprise.... just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t confuse it with `.env.example` file – it is used as an information file for all team members to know what keys and values may be needed & `.env.example` is never loaded. See [The Official Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/configuration#environment-configuration)

If you install Laravel via Composer, this file will automatically be renamed to `.env`. Otherwise, you should rename the file manually.

The `.env` file is your environment variables. So you’re giving your Laravel app the information which is relevant to its local environment.

According to above what you need to do is as below :

```
{{ env('BUSINESS_ID') }} // returns 1234
{{ env('APP_URL') }} //  returns App Url
```

Then from console you need to clear cache.

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: Because of config caching, `env` helper does not work in production, you need to use `config` instead